# Redirect to "This site is unavailable"

Tags: php, html, web

How could I send an error to the person who tries to connect to my site?
More specificaly, an error that says the site is offline or does not exist.

Example: when you go to: http://aoihjehopejhoitjaephjo.com you'll see "This site is unreachable"
I need my site to show that page.
Does anyone know, how / if it's possible to achieve this?

for a screenshot on the error I need: https://gyazo.com/2c7926238572e73f2757db577bb16bae

Comment: Depending on what error you want, either remove your DNS records or send a 500.  You need to understand what these errors mean.

Comment: I need it to show this error: https://gyazo.com/2c7926238572e73f2757db577bb16bae

Comment: Put whatever you want the user to see in the index.php script

Comment: look up apache directives, assuming your system's on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use .htaccess you can insert the following lines:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
Redirect 500 /
</IfModule>
```

This will redirect everyone to the internal server error page. You can change 500 to any of the other error codes which can be found using a search engine, or to a directory/page you've created specifically for people to see.

Answer (score 0):

I did it by redirecting my main domain: www.domaindomain.com/index.html to  www.domaindomain.com/file.html.

My file.html will display an error message.

Comment: Cool, but what is the difference between this and just using index.html and removing the need to redirect